# Create User function is not working in node.js using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prisma

below is where my function is, and the createUser is not working, until const {firstName, id} = req.body is working the name and id show up but don't create the user. If you need more informations just ask. Thank you!

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
    
    const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    
    module.exports = {
        async createUser(req, res) {
            try {
                const {firstName, id} = req.body
                console.log({firstName, id}) //until here is working the name and id show up but don't create the user
        
                const user = await prisma.UserInfo.create({
                    data: {
                        firstName,
                        id
                    }
                });
    
                return res.json(user)
        
            } catch (error) {
                return res.json({error})
                
            }
        },
    
        async teste(req, res) {
            try {
                return res.json("again")
            }
            catch(error) {
                return res.json({error})
            }
        }
    }
```

[that image show what error show up in my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg7Tf.png)

here is my routes

```
const express = require("express");
const UserController = require("./UserController");
let router = express.Router();

router.post("/user",  UserController.createUser);

module.exports = router
```

here is my server

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./routes.js');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json())

app.use(require("./routes.js"))
app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log('server at port 3333 is running');
});
```

here is my schema in prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider          = "sqlserver"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("DATABASE_SHADOW_URL")
}

model UserInfo {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String?
  lastName  String?
  email     String  @unique
  password  String
  age       Int
  role      String?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed the object to prisma.UserInfo.create() method.

As per my understanding after seeing the error message, You need to pass the properties email, password, and age to Prisma.UserInfo.create() with the property id and firstName.

Here the problem is, When you going to create the record in the userInfo table, you have only passed the property id and firstName.  But in your database migration, you set that like email, password, and age these things are not going to be null.

So the following properties must be passed to prisma.UserInfo.create() method

```
const {email, password, age, firstName} = req.body;

prisma.UserInfo.create({
  data: {email, password, age, firstName // firstName is optional
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for your explanation!! I hope it helps other people besides me